# Como crear un Trigger en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

la verdad no tengo idea de cómo crear Triggers o Disparadores, recien comienzo  a estudiarlos pero queria que me ayudaran con uno en especifico.
Estoy desarrollando una aplicacin punto de venta y quiero evitar que se habrá un turno en una caja si aun esta abierto otro.

```
describe turno_caja;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_turno      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| numero_turno  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_usuario    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_caja       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| fecha_inicio  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fecha_cierre  | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| fondo_inicial | decimal(8,2) | NO   |     | 0.00    |                |
| fondo_final   | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sucursal      | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_sesion     | varchar(40)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

El turno se considera abierto si fecha_cierre es NULL.
Cuando inserto o creo un nuevo turno pues por defecto, como ven, este es NULL y hasta que lo cierro se ingresa la fecha de cierre.
Ya hago las validaciones en PHP y todo bien, no he tenido problemas, pero me sentiria más tranquilo añadiendo esas capas de seguridad en MySQL también, es por ello que comienzo a estudiar los TRIGGERS.

Asi que basicamente lo que quiero es un BEFORE INSERT,
Un disparador que verifique si hay un turno abierto en una caja especifica.
Es decir que cheque si `fecha_cierre is NULL`
Si hay un turno abierto pues lanzar un error o algo y si no hay ningún turno abierto en tal caja pues permitir la inserción.

Yo en PHP hago una sentencia tipo
`select * from turno_caja where id_caja=? and fecha_cierre is null`

Edición
El trigger que he intentado es

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER verificacion_turno_cerrado
BEFORE INSERT
ON turno_caja FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE contador INT;
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO contador
    FROM turno_caja
    WHERE ;//???
    
    IF contador = 0 THEN
        //Insertar
    ELSE
        //Lanzar error
    END IF; 

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

en el where quisiera algo como lo hago en PHP `id_caja=? and fecha_cierre is null`

Comment: @BetaM La verdad no entendí su comentario,

Comment: @BetaM listo! tomé el ejemplo de donde estoy aprendiendo y quise utilizarlo en mi caso.

Comment: @BetaM utilizo mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de un *trigger before/after insert*, tienes acceso a los datos de la fila que se está insertando con la variable `new`, que tiene la misma estructura que cualquier registro de la tabla para la que creas el trigger.

Así, en `New.id_caja` tienes el valor de `id_caja` que se está intentando insertar, por lo que la consulta para obtener la cuenta de cajas abiertas sería algo como:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
      INTO contador
      FROM turno_caja
     WHERE id_caja = New.id_caja
       and fecha_cierre is null
```

Para dejar que se realice la inserción, simplemente no haces nada, al tereminar el trigger se hará. Para prevenir que se inserte la fila, lanzas un error valiéndote de [`signal`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html), por ejemplo:

```
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'La caja aún está abierta';
```

Ya te toca a ti poner las piezas juntas, con lo escrito aquí considero que tienes lo necesario para completar la tarea.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tiene mucho sentido, no conocia aún el uso de new. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Un placer ser de ayuda.